# Preencher um campo conforme a referência selecionada

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Estou fazendo um sistema em Laravel, e estou em uma tela onde eu listo a referencia da tabela Produto, e conforme a referencia selecionada, preciso que apareça no outro campo o produto cadastrado com a referencia selecionada.
Para isso, nao sei como fazer,acho que não posso buscar os dados no Controller, já que teria que atualizar em "tempo real", talvez utilizar um javascript para isso, ou outra alternativa via Laravel que eu não conheça...

**Controller:**

```
public function create(){
        $pgmtos = Pgmto::all();
        $tams = Tam::all();
        $produtos = Product::all();

        return view('sale-create ', [
            'pgmtos' => $pgmtos,
            'tams'=>$tams,
            'produtos'=>$produtos
            
        ]);
    }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="produto">Produto: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                            
                            <select name="produto" id="produto" class="form-control sale-screen">
                                {{--Aqui vai ser preenchido com as informaçoes--}}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[Print de demonstracao][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqOGd.png

Comment: Queira seguir as instruções dadas quando [perguntou da primeira vez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/583435/70), editando sua postagem original (restaurando-a se necessário). Para evitar duplicidade de informações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas pode ser usado naquela postagem se restaurada.